# JavaScript - How do I stop a JavaScript If/Else Tree?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a problem with the code below, when it reaches the **}else{** it executes the error message and then redirects to the users provided URL. What it is supposed to do is just display the error not redirect to the website that they typed in the input box. Is there a way to make it to stop after is displays the error message?

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-5 offset-lg-1 text"><input class="border rounded form-control-lg" type="text" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-duration="900" data-aos-delay="1500" name="input-01" id = "input-01" placeholder="Call URL" required=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-5"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id = "start-call" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-duration="900" data-aos-delay="2000" type="button" style="margin: 160px;width: 135px;" onclick = "goToCall()" >Start Call</button></div>

function goToCall(){
const url = new URL(window.location = document.getElementById('input-01').value);

console.log(url.host);   
if (url.host === 'example.com'){
window.location = document.getElementById('input-01').value;
return true;
}else{
swal({
    title: "Invalid URL",
    text: "Thats was an invalid DropCall URL.",
    icon: "error",
});
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: you don't need to set the window.location when constructing the new URL(), just set it in the if block alone

Comment: You probably don't want to assign  the user given URL to `window.location` in the `URL` constructor